# HERE Geocoder Autocomplete API matchLevel parameter

Tags: geocoding, here-api

Is there a way to get results restricted based on matchLevel? 
So if we are using geocoding to search for cities, we could use:

```
matchLevel : 'city'
```

to get results with only that?

Currently when sending request with query for example "London" we get all kinds of results with  districts, counties, cities. I don't see a way to restrict those results to just city. Using `resultType=areas` is not enough. For a workaround currently we filter results after the response to show only those with `matchLevel=city` but we've increased `maxresults` to get enough to filter from. Is there maybe some beta/hidden parameter we could use?

Comment: Hi, you can probably filter a response result by looping in your code. Or can you provide your code then we can help.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Yes, as I wrote we currently filter results. I've just hoped you have some parameter that could simplify things. Limiting results on database query level is usually more efficient than filtering. Anyway, thanks for taking an interest. :o)

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: @harunB10 unfortunately not. Only thing you can do is to pull data, and filter results with JS function. Not very efficient, but it's the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's not possible to do it directly in API, the only solution is in fact filtering results. For anyone in need, this is what I use. You can adjust it to your needs.

```
request.onload = function () {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        // Success!
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

        var list = [];
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.suggestions.length; i++) {
            if (data.suggestions[i].matchLevel == "city" && list.indexOf(data.suggestions[i].address.city + ', ' + data.suggestions[i].address.country) < 0) {
                list.push(data.suggestions[i].address.city + ', ' + data.suggestions[i].address.country);
            }
        }

    }
};
```